# How can ı solve this python selennium problem?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url_1 = "https://imdb.com"
driver.get(url_1)
```

İt's super easy code but it does not work
ı get
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54250/devtools/browser/1584417f-6522-4aba-a8e8-53b832ffe695 error

opens the site, but the site instantly closes and gives this error
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54250/devtools/browser/1584417f-6522-4aba-a8e8-53b832ffe695 error

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stacktrace.